# Is Dispose neccessary for the class I put in ServiceHost

Tags: wcf, idisposable, servicehost

I am hosting my WCF Services in a Managed Application.
I use [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) class for this.

Regarding the class I am hosting inside the ServiceHost, should implement IDispoable ? When it will be called if i implemented :IDisposable ?
When i call servicehost.Close() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason to implement IDisposable is if your class wraps an unmanaged resource.

Whether this is inside ServiceHost has no bearing.

Comment: when does dispose for this class is called ? when no other class holds a reference for it ? (since i never dispose it directly), so the only time this class be disposed is when its ServiceHost wrapper is disposed ?